# Can not include javascript file from WEB-INF directory in JSP.

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

How to include a file in the following folder WEB-INF\includes\header.js in jsp using tomcat. I have the included the following in jsp file but it does not work "

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/includes/header.js"></script>
```

". It is not getting the header.js and when i view source and try to click on the src link it says resource not found 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<%@include file="../foo.js" %>
</script>
```

foo.js is under WEB-INF/jsp and the file include it is under WEB-INF/jsp/common

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Put a `"/"` before `"WEB-INF"` like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/WEB-INF/includes/header.js"/>'></script>
```

and it will work fine. :)

Comment: I find this answer clearer and better aligned to OP in the use of exact path instead of using relative path with jsp include.

Comment: I don't get it. This is how I gave it in my JSP:                                                 <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/WEB-INF/js/angular/angular.min.js"/>'></script>