# How to calling js code in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `html` with `js` in one file. I want had two different files `js`, and `html`.

This is all in one file (first case), and this code work :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>menu</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <form id="commentForm" method="post" action="Servlet" name="add_data">

        <label for="username">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

        <button type="submit">Register</button>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
            // It has the name attribute "registration"
            $("form[name='add_data']").validate({
                // Specify validation rules
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    }
                },

                messages: {
                    username: "Please enter your firstname"
                },

                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I create second file `valid.js` and move all JavaScript code, this is don't work (second case):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Меню</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="valid.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <form id="commentForm" method="post" action="Servlet" name="add_data">

        <label for="username">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

        <button type="submit">Register</button>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And file `valid.js` which exist in same folder with `html` file. This is copy of code in `<script>` block in first example.

```
$(function() {
    $("form[name='add_data']").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: "Please enter your firstname"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

`HTML` and `JS` files in same directory. May be I need call in html my js code?
There my mistake? Why second case don't work? How to fix this issue?

Comment: add  valid js function code inside $(document).ready(function() {}); block.

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: Seems to me like it should work, if everything you've said is accurate. If you right click and view source, and then click on your valid.js, it should take you to a text readout of the file. If not, then your reference is wrong. @NagaSaiA, `$(function() {})` is a shorthand version of document.ready for jquery.

Comment: I just created plunker and it works perfectly - http://plnkr.co/edit/cRUr4AeWGMoJhEv5MRJw?p=preview

Comment: as @Nieminen mentioned this seems to be reference error

Comment: @Naga Sai sintaxis error. I think ma by reson is specific java servlet... I use directory WEB-INF for cecuridy and servlet get only my jsp file without js. But this hypothesis. When I use crome console I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < valid.js:2 . And when i click on Frames->Scripts->valid.js when he show me my HTML not js file. It's very strange...

Comment: @Pavel, Could you please provide screenshot of error and provide complete error and also where did you place the js file .. in the same folder where html file resides?

Comment: @Pavel, from the error I see that there is some unwanted string "<" that is causing the error ..Please fix the errors in valid.js at line 2,as per the console error

Comment: @NagaSaiA  http://savepic.ru/14576780.png http://savepic.ru/14567564.png http://savepic.ru/14571660.png + http://savepic.ru/14592143.pngthis screens

Comment: You have to use your script like this <script type="text/javascript" src="valid.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP and JS files code are working fine and I have created plunker for reference -
http://plnkr.co/edit/cRUr4AeWGMoJhEv5MRJw?p=preview

Issue from the screenshot and console error is that the placement of JS file in your directory sructure.

All files under WEB-INF is unavailable to the outside. Place your static file under WEB-INF folder and move JS files out of WEB-INF and it will work.

Change the reference of js path in the reference after moving valid.js out of WEB-INF

```
 <script src="**valid.js**"></script>
```

Comment: no unfoutenately it's don't work I put my js file in root webapp folder and IDE do refactor src="../../valid.js" it's don't work and I try copypast You're path "**valid.js**"(but I don't understeand what is mean **) it same result what You see in printscreen.

Comment: try adding type="text/javascript"  .....                      
<script src="valid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Can you share the console log now?

Comment: absolutely same how on screen which I send. May by issue in ../../ This is mean that need able for inner WEB-INF and then go up = ../.. but I dont access to WEB-INF. Need come in webapp folder from above but how...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766914/include-javascript-file-from-inside-web-inf

Comment: Yessss!!!!! Thank You!!! In You're last link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766914/include-javascript-file-from-inside-web-inf last solution <%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/valid.js" %> is work and work inner WEB-INF!!! You're greate Thank You!!!

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `<script src="valid.js"></script>` at the end of body tag.

Comment: What is the problem with the code in question? It should also work! Explain why is it not working?

Comment: He's using the `$(function() {});` which doesn't really matter if he's importing the JS file before or after since the JS will run after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Look his one file code where his js is below form, and with two files its in head tag. Since that all info he gave without any console errors I gave that answer. It sometimes don;t work on chrome if its in head for no reason Ive had same issues...

Comment: it works on chrome and doesn't matter where he is importing JS file - http://plnkr.co/edit/cRUr4AeWGMoJhEv5MRJw?p=preview

Comment: When you add 'ready' but since he didn't add it it won'y work if its in head.

Comment: @NoNameNeedToKnow as Nieminen mentioned $(function() {}) is a shorthand version of document.ready for jquery, I just updated plunker with same and no issues

Comment: @NoNameNeedToKnow Following that logic, importing jQuery inside the `<head>` shouldn't work either, yet it works in the first example he showed us. It doesn't matter where he's importing his JS file, that's why the `$(function() {}) ;` is there.

Comment: Idk who down/up voted my question, but by your answer where you add some code, he didnt ask you what is missing he asked why code isnt working and I gace just answer how his code works on my pc, I didnt try to edit code or do anything else like you did u added extra '$(function() {}) ;' but his code has one your have two explain why its not working as one but it is as two. While I just added answer where it works for me by adding it to the bottom of the page with his code not my code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to also work in the second case.  You could try putting the `script` tag at the bottom of the page and use this tag

`script src="valid.js" type="text/javascript"`

with the type property included to be consistent with the first case, and you may want to serve static files in a dev environment using some sort of web [server](http://harpjs.com/) instead of dragging the files into the browser.  But, it should work.