# JavaScript - Error 404 resource not found

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, external

I had a java script in my JSP, which worked fine. Now I want to move it to it's own file (abc.js). I created js-Folder and placed it there.
I tried to include it with `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/abc.js"></script>` which links to `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/js/abc.js` (from link in HTML-Code of the page). I think this should be correct, isn't it?

Nevertheless I get errors in the browser console (`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () abc.js`)

**Do I have to register the .js somewhere to be recognized?**

Edit: My project structure is like this:

```
ProjectName
   |---WEB-INF
          |---page.jsp (that wants to include abc.js)
          |---js
               |---abc.js
```

Comment: what's the path of the page you're including the script file in?

Comment: @H77 it's direct in the /WEB-INF/-Folder of my project

Comment: If you enter http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/js/abc.js in your browser, you can see the file?

Comment: @Kloker no I also get 404 not found. But what would be the right path if that's the wrong? I speculated on '...or is not willing to disclose that one exists'. I already tried src="/WEB_INF/js/abc.js" or src="abc.js" (while placing it direct in WEB-INF-folder) but got the same result.

Comment: Have you tried this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107788/how-include-an-external-js-file-in-a-jsp-page

Comment: @Kloker thank you so much, this finally seems to work. thanks thanks thanks.

Comment: @Kloker for this solution I had to place js folder the same level as WEB-INF. I was just wondering, placing it in WEB-INF and modifying src to src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/js/abc.js" would work as well but it doesn't. Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WEB-INF directory is not publicly accessible. Your HTML file accesses the JS file over an public URL. Details see here: [Include javascript file from inside WEB-INF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766914/include-javascript-file-from-inside-web-inf)

So the solution for your problem is to place the JS file on the same level as the WEB-INF directory, so that it is served publicly and adjust the src link accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/abc.js"></script>
```

([How include an external JS file in a JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107788/how-include-an-external-js-file-in-a-jsp-page))

Comment: thanks again, this also worked for my css files, so I finally god rid of these ugly <%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%>-Tags.